# NServicebus tapping servicecontrol events

Tags: nservicebus

I am not able to get this work for some reason. The question is, my host is installed under D:\NServiceBus**********.NsbAudit.QueueService and ServiceControl is installed under C:\Program Files (x86)\Particular Software\ServiceControl.

I see the messages in servicecontrol log: 2016-02-16 18:31:04.5882|300|Info|ServiceControl.EventLog.GenericAuditHandler|Event: MessageFailed emitted 2016-02-16 18:31:04.5882|48|Info|ServiceControl.EventLog.GenericAuditHandler|Event: MessageFailed emitted 2016-02-16 18:31:05.1498|181|Info|ServiceControl.EventLog.GenericAuditHandler|Event: MessageFailed emitted

The question i have is, how is the subscription working here? Though i have defined in my config :

how does NServicebus knows that i am subscribing to that event and that it needs to send a message to **********.NsbAudit.QueueService that i have created locally.

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/contracts) specipcally [this section](http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/contracts#custom-notification-and-alerting-using-servicecontrol-events-subscribing-to-servicecontrol-events)

Answer (score 0):

As for: `The question i have is, how is the subscription working here`

When a subscriber start it sends a subscription message to the publisher (ServiceControl in your case), then when the publisher publishes the event it look up the subscriber list and sends an event to each subscriber in the list.

[Take a look here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/publish-subscribe/) and [here](http://docs.particular.net/samples/pubsub/)

Does this make sense?